# jQuery.after won't accept </tr> to end an element after starting one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is generated by some other software, each row contains 50 columns and I'm trying to break the columns by adding a `</tr><tr>` to the end of a `<td>` element.

This is the code that is generated on the fly:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="col1" scope="col">08/22/2014</td>
<td class="col2" scope="col">Share</td>
<td class="col3" scope="col">Success</td>
<td class="col4" scope="col">Some notes</td>
<td class="col5" scope="col">8/23/2014</td>
  ...etc
<td class="col51" scope="col">End column</td>
```

If I use this Jquery:

```
$( ".col4").after('</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td>');
```

It appends but doesn't respect the `</tr>`....it ignores it and adds the `<tr>` on, resulting this code.

```
<td class="col3" scope="col">Success</td>
<td class="col4" scope="col">Some notes</td>
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<td class="col5" scope="col">etc...</td>
```

Wonder what the best way to get JQUERY to append that `<TR>` for me?  When I modify the code in Firebug, breaking the rows gives me the desired output, just not sure how to get JQUERY to give me the `</tr>`.

Comment: DOM doesn't work that way, each tag becomes an Element. You can't insert opening and closing tags separately.

Comment: Try using `.wrap()` instead.

Comment: .wrap seemed interesting but looks like it'll just wrap my <td></td> which won't accomplish the </tr> break I'm trying, unless I'm using it wrong?

Comment: select the first four `<td>` elements, then wrap: `:lt(4)`

Comment: Thanks Brian - I'm trying that now.

Comment: I tried this:   $( "td:lt(4)").wrap('<tr></tr>');   but it wrapped a <tr></tr> around each element instead of the entire thing?  Seems like I'm really close.

Comment: Try appending the tr to the tbody and then appending the found td elements into it.

Comment: Thanks Jon!  What you are mentioning above sounds logical, but I think I'm getting over my head, a jquery novice and hate to keep asking for exact code, I might have a hard time taking this one myself from here. Maybe I'll brainstorm another way.

Comment: You may need the forms prevAll and wrapAll.  Something like $('.col4').prevAll().wrapAll('<tr></tr>') -- finds the marker, gets the folks to its left and puts the new row tag around the group.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the help. I'm pretty sure I probably could have done it with your code, just too much of a newbie to figure it out!  Thank you for giving me some things to try.

Comment: I am betting this is not the appropriate way to do this to begin with.   Only if you have absolutely no control over the original generation would it be.  I think folks are just interested in pointing out the flexibility of jQuery.  You should either give a lot better clues as to where the breaks are, or you should not format the original as a table, or you should just format it correctly at generation, or...

Comment: Great point, thank you. In the end I had to go a completely different route as the "no control over the table" thing presented other challenges once I got past this.  But I understand this better now and thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ughdernt/3/)**

[Detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the last 2 cells, append them to `tbody` and wrap them with `tr`

```
$('.col4').nextAll().detach().appendTo('tbody').wrapAll('<tr />')
```

Comment: `.detach()` i s the way to go! The only practical answer so far. +1 :)

Comment: Ok that seems definitely like the right direction. I implemented just as above and it started to lay things out correctly. I think I need to research what NextAll() does to make a few mods but it's right on track.

Comment: `nextAll()` starts from the selector but selects all after it, not including. If you want to include the selector do `nextAll().andSelf().detach()` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert tags separately using JQuery.  For instance, take the following code, which inserts a `<p>` element into the body:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $("body").append("<p>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the Firefox inspector, this is what the DOM looks like:

[image: dom]

Thus, `$("...").append("<p>")`, `$("...").append("</p>")`, `$("...").append("<p></p>")` all modify the DOM in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot handle incomplete or illegally formatted HTML as DOM elements.  You want to gather up the correctly formatted children before that column and stuff them into a new complete `<tr>`.

If you want to handle HTML as text, you need to turn it into text with `html()` and paste it together into actual, correctly closed HTML, and then convert it back.